# Change the size of a Custom View at Runtime Android

Tags: android-layout, android, android-custom-view

I'm changing the `height` and the `width` of my `CustomView` which extends Android `View` in runtime like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {          
            if(!initialized) {          
                int containerHeight = instance.getHeight();
                int containerWidth = instance.getWidth();
                myView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (containerHeight * HEIGHT_RATIO);
                myView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (containerWidth * WIDTH_RATIO);
                instance.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                initialized = true;
            }
        }
```

this code is in the `container view` Constructor.

In addition my `CustomView` `onMeasure()` is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // maximum width we should use
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Where the `width` and `height` I specified are at the same size of the green rectangle.

**My Question is:** why does the actual size of my custom view (red rectangle) is not at the same size as I gave as input in the `LayoutParams` ?

Comment: Try commenting out your onMeasure(), I don't think you need that in its current implementation.

Comment: That didn't do the trick. I'm using this implementation to reduce the time that my view is being measured, since I know that in my case the size is always exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the drawing of the `CustomView`. In `onDraw()`, I took the `width` and `height` of the `canvas` instead of the `View` itself.

Comment: In my case...I design and customView which getting timer based continuous painting in X-direction. This CView puted in HScrollView. Any idea how can change size of view in this case!!!

Answer (score 0):

not sure what object you're working with for your view, but you might try something like this:

CustomViewget.Window().setLayout(370, 480); //Controls width and height

Comment: My custom view is a VIEW and not a DIALOG.

Answer (score 0):

The sizes might not be calculated properly at the time of calling, so you may need to place your code in a handler and run it on post so that it gets done after everything else on the UI thread is done. Try the following code.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    //check sizes and update sizes here
    });
```